# Populate third column based on conditional values from two other columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Simple dataframe in pandas:

```
A  B  C  
1  1  
1  0  
0  1  
0  0
```

Say I'd like to populate column C with a 1 if A and B both are 1, else 0.
If I try to do something like:

```
    if df['A'] == 1 and df['B'] == 1:
        df['C'] = 1
    else:
        df['C'] = 0
```

I get something like:

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Which code will be the most efficient and how should it be used?

Answer (score 1):

#### Multiply

```
df.assign(C=df.A * df.B)

   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  0
```

---

#### `all`

Don't do this

```
df.assign(C=df[['A', 'B']].astype(bool).all(1).astype(int))

   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @piRSquared.  Maybe I didn't frame the problem adequately.  I wanted to use a conditional statement on two columns to generate a third as in the example I gave.  You have solved the "and" problem but I also need a solution to the "or" problem such as:        ` if A == 1 or B == 1 then C = 1`

Comment: @kozowh the permutations of various logical combinations are infinite.  It is a lot of effort to attempt to answer while covering a high level of generality.  You could produce an example that adequately covers what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I did manage to find a solution to this issue thanks to Stack Overflow members.  Here are the general forms.        
        `df['STEC'] = [(1 if i or j == 1 else 0) for i,j in zip(df['stx2'], df['stx1'])]
df['EHEC'] = [(1 if i and j == 1 else 0) for i,j in zip(df['eae'], df['STEC'])]
df['O157'] = [(1 if (i or j == 1) and k == 1 else 0) for i,j,k in zip(df['rfb'],df['LF'], df['EHEC'])]`   These seem to work!